# How to convert an SparseArray into a Matrix?

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I have the following sparse array and I want to change it to a matrix. Could you please tell me how to do that?

```
  ddd = {0, 
  0}[{-35.57724148951671 - 3.275033710357711*^-17 E^(
  Complex[0, 1] (
  0.8660254037844386 kx - 0.5 ky)) + 5.670630368171192*^-16 E^(
  Complex[0, 
    1] ((-0.8660254037844386)
      kx + 0.5 ky)) - 3.275033710357711*^-17 E^(
 Complex[0, 1] (0.8660254037844386 kx + 0.5 ky)), 
  3.790334960911032*^-14 - 0.4879058168792183 E^(
 Complex[0, 
   1] ((-0.8660254037844386) kx - 0.5 ky)) - 7.281208034172971 E^(
 Complex[0, 1] (
  0.8660254037844386 kx - 0.5 ky)) + 0.4879058168792254 E^(
  Complex[0, 
    1] ((-0.8660254037844386) kx + 0.5 ky)) + 7.281208034172971 E^(
  Complex[0, 1] (0.8660254037844386 kx + 0.5 ky))}, {
  5.824627900190777*^-14 + 7.281208034172958 E^(
  Complex[0, 
    1] ((-0.8660254037844386)
      kx - 0.5 ky)) + 0.4879058168792218 E^(
  Complex[0, 1] (
   0.8660254037844386 kx - 0.5 ky)) - 7.2812080341729795` E^(
 Complex[0, 
   1] ((-0.8660254037844386) kx + 0.5 ky)) - 0.4879058168792218 E^(
 Complex[0, 1] (
  0.8660254037844386 kx + 0.5 ky)), \
 -37.215639422874965` - 5.329957889634341 E^(
 Complex[0, 
   1] ((-0.8660254037844386) kx - 0.5 ky)) - 5.329957889634305 E^(
 Complex[0, 1] (
  0.8660254037844386 kx - 0.5 ky)) - 5.32995788963426 E^(
 Complex[0, 
   1] ((-0.8660254037844386) kx + 0.5 ky)) - 5.329957889634305 E^(
 Complex[0, 1] (0.8660254037844386 kx + 0.5 ky))}]
```

I want to change it to a matrix so I can easily substitute kx and ky by numerical values and working with it as a Matrix.

I know I can use a Table and call each element of the sparse array to construct the matrix, but I was wondering if there is special command or an easier way to do it.

Comment: Normally, you can convert from a sparse array to a matrix using Normal[]. But your ddd is not a sparse array, and doesn't even seem to be a legal expression. (Observe the part {0,0}[ ] --- the square brackets here don't make sense.)

Comment: Thank you, I tried to separate some rows and columns from a larger sparse array and I expected it to be sparse array as well.

Comment: Try building a minimal working example... one with small dimensions but exhibiting the same behavior (and with legal syntax!)